# batch file to remove characters in a txt file and rename it with the current date

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I've been researching this for days now so forgive me if it's already been answered. I finally gave up and contacted our IT department but don't want to bug the same guy again for a couple of issues I'm having and know NOTHING about batch language. I need to remove all quotations " and dashes - from an entire text file regardless of the size. It may be 10 lines or it may be 50,000 lines. This is the batch file he wrote for me:

```
@(For /F Tokens^=1*Delims^=^" %%A In (c:\test\test.txt) Do @Echo %%A%%B)>"c:\test\output.txt"
@(For /F Tokens^=1*Delims^=- %%A In (c:\test\output.txt) Do @Echo %%A%%B)>"c:\test\output1.txt"


del c:\test\test.txt
rename c:\test\output1.txt test.txt
del c:\test\output.txt
```

(I will obviously have a different directory and file name) My issue is it's not removing them from the ENTIRE file and I can't figure out how to add looping into this current script since I'm clueless. Also, MY file will always be named with the current days date in format of mmddyyyy so I don't know what to replace with the "test" file name he provided me. Is there even a way to do that? Another program I use it's <%dmmddyyyy> but I tried that and it did not work. Sorry for the long question, this is my first post. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me!!

Comment: You really have two unrelated programming questions - 1) how to edit the file, and 2) how to get today's date in mmddyyyy format. For a convenient way to edit text files, check out [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), a hybrid JScript/batch regular expression utility. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine without the need of any 3rd party exe file. Once you have JREPL.BAT, you can edit your file with one simple command - `call jrepl "[\q-]" "" /xseq /f yourFile.txt /o -`

Comment: I failed to mention this will reside on an ASP server of which I have no control to install or run any third party applications such as PowerShell so my only option is to run a custom task through the STP software program to run a .bat file. Not sure any of the above options will work unfortunately but I’ll keep digging for answers. Thanks!

Comment: PowerShell is native to Windows. If you can execute a batch script from your server, then you should be able to execute a PowerShell script or command. Or if you can create and execute a batch script on your server, then you can also include JREPL.BAT - it is simply another batch script that also happens to include JScript. There is no other installation needed other than the script.

Comment: @dbenham you are a genius!! It took me a little bit to figure out what you meant but I did and it works!! Thank you SOOOO much!!!